# reduce apk size flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to know whether we will delete the previous app-release.apk file in the directory of my application  `build\app\outputs\flutter-apk` or if it is deleted by itself when we run the command

```
flutter build apk split-per-abi
```

Help me out as I am new to this.

I tried different users' Questions which were answered and YouTube videos but my concept was not resolved.

Comment: Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: I didn't had any senior with me in contact at the time so I was afraid whether I may not delete any necessary files at my time of release to playstore. Though I tried it my self now and I am clear now through some research. We can delete those and after running the specific command to shrink the apk size the files can be deleted and they are re created agani. Thanks for contributing dear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All files in the `build` folder will be removed and rewritten. By running the following command `build` folder will also be cleaned

```
flutter clean
```

Also when you run a command to generate a new APK, it will remove the current one and will create a new one.